# What's wrong with my tikz code?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

For some reason the code below is giving me the errors

`Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, I could not read the plot coordinates near ') '. Please check for format mistakes.`

But I just don't understand why or how to fix it. It seems that I cannot specify math expression in the y coordinates?!

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line/.style={black, thick},
    declare function={foo(\r,\x) = (\x)^(\r); },
    ]
    \begin{axis}[
      width=8cm, height=8cm, %
      xmin=0, xmax=1, %
      ymode=log, axis on top]

      \addplot [line, domain=0:1, samples=200]{foo(2, x)};

      \foreach \r in {1,2,3,4} %
      {
        \addplot [line, domain=0:1, samples=200]{foo(\r, x)};
        \addplot [draw=black]
        coordinates {
          (2^(-\r), 1)
          (2^(-\r), foo(\r, x))
          %(2^(-\r), x^(3)) %% Same error
          % (2^(-\r), 0.002) %% This works
        };
      }
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add braces. Otherwise the parser is confused and does not know when the brackets delimit coordinates or arguments of a function.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line/.style={black, thick},
    declare function={foo(\r,\x) = (\x)^(\r); },
    ]
    \begin{axis}[
      width=8cm, height=8cm, %
      xmin=0, xmax=1, %
      ymode=log, axis on top]

      \addplot [line, domain=0:1, samples=200]{foo(2, x)};

      \foreach \r in {1,2,3,4} %
      {
        \addplot [line, domain=0:1, samples=200]{foo(\r, x)};
        \addplot [draw=black]
        coordinates {
          (2^(-\r), 1)
          (2^(-\r),{ foo(\r, x)})
         ({2^(-\r)},{ x^(3)}) %% 
           ({2^(-\r)}, 0.002) %% This works
        };
      }
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I will accept this once I can. I don't understand why the x-coordinates work with braces but not the y-coordinates

Comment: @Tohiko The problem is that the closing `)` may either delimit the coordinate or the function. We have to help the parser a little bit. On the other hand, the x coordinate gets delimited by a comma, not the same delimiter as the function.